# How to cache data from firebase real-time db and store it locally in Hive db in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to save data from firebase real-time db to Hive in my Flutter app, below you can find an example of the data I get from firebase realtime db. Please guide me on how I can store such data in Hive by an example.
Thanks a million!
Here is the data that I receive from my Realtime db:

```
{"-Muo8YmvSfvYddbmSjkc":{"author":"لینکن","category":"success","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xffffa057)","id":"2022-02-01 11:48:31.436277","startColor":"Color(0xffffb157)","title":"زندگینامه لینکن"},"-MuoDZ3JBpMfIdzjrame":{"author":"قرآن شریف","category":"qurani","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xff8f7afe)","id":"2022-02-01 12:10:23.307112","startColor":"Color(0xffd76ef5)","title":"کشتی حضرت نوح"},"-Mup5O85qgPvXjjdgduY":{"author":"الیف شافاک","category":"narrative","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xff73a1f9)","id":"2022-02-01 16:14:19.175932","startColor":"Color(0xff6dc8f3)","title":"مولانا و شمس"},"-MupljOhghLgoYfQhCyP":{"author":"آریانا گرند ","category":"story","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xfff8556d)","id":"2022-02-01 19:23:31.863484","startColor":"Color(0xffff5b95)","title":"جک و لوبیای سحر آمیز"}}
```

Comment: What state management are you using for the app, If not you can check the bloc pattern, it has a hydrated bloc which uses the hive under the hood, you can check that one.

Comment: I am using Provider. It is a small app

Answer (score 0):

Your data you have looks like it is in json/string format already. Simply put it into Hive.

```
var data = {"-Muo8YmvSfvYddbmSjkc":{"author":"لینکن","category":"success","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xffffa057)","id":"2022-02-01 11:48:31.436277","startColor":"Color(0xffffb157)","title":"زندگینامه لینکن"},"-MuoDZ3JBpMfIdzjrame":{"author":"قرآن شریف","category":"qurani","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xff8f7afe)","id":"2022-02-01 12:10:23.307112","startColor":"Color(0xffd76ef5)","title":"کشتی حضرت نوح"},"-Mup5O85qgPvXjjdgduY":{"author":"الیف شافاک","category":"narrative","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xff73a1f9)","id":"2022-02-01 16:14:19.175932","startColor":"Color(0xff6dc8f3)","title":"مولانا و شمس"},"-MupljOhghLgoYfQhCyP":{"author":"آریانا گرند ","category":"story","content":"این یک متن آزمایشی است.","endColor":"Color(0xfff8556d)","id":"2022-02-01 19:23:31.863484","startColor":"Color(0xffff5b95)","title":"جک و لوبیای سحر آمیز"}};
var box = await Hive.openBox('box');
box.put('myData', data);

// To get the data
var storedData = box.get('myData');
```

Comment: It is a map of String and dynamics

Comment: {"-Muo8YmvSfvYddbmSjkc":{"author":"sometext","category":"success","content":"some texts","endColor":"Color(0xffffa057)","id":"2022-02-01 11:48:31.436277","startColor":"Color(0xffffb157)","title":"sometext"},

Comment: Yes. The dynamic itself is already stringified looking at your output. When you tried it, it didn't work ?